# Ancestor Query causes API error 4 (datastore_v3: NEED_INDEX): no matching index found error

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I'm having huge difficulties with an ancestor query.

Here is the code that works:

```
...
uk := datastore.NewKey(c, config.DatastoreDuelIdKind, did, 0, nil)
_, err := datastore.NewQuery(config.DatastoreQuestionInDuelKind).Ancestor(uk).GetAll(c, &roundsPlayedInDuel)
...
```

The above code yields the correct results. Now, if I add an **Order** filter on a property of **config.DatastoreQuestionInDuelKind** the query fails with the NEED_INDEX error.

But this one fails:

```
_, err := datastore.NewQuery(config.DatastoreQuestionInDuelKind).Order("RoundNumber").Ancestor(uk).GetAll(c, &roundsPlayedInDuel)
```

The only difference being the added **Order** filter.

Now, I have defined an index in index.yaml like so:

indexes:

```
- kind: gcx_Round_Id_Duel_Id
  properties:
  - name: DId
  - name: RoundNumber
```

From App Engine Dashboard I can see, that it is serving. Still getting the index error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Your index is missing the 'ancestor' property, and the query you've doesn't appear to be using 'DId', so no need to include that:

```
- kind: gcx_Round_Id_Duel_Id
  ancestor: yes
  properties:
  - name: RoundNumber
```

You have to explicitly define this index because you're combining the ancestor query with a sort - the automatic indexes will allow you to do either of those individually. (So given you're fetching all of the entities, it would probably be more efficient for you to forego the query-ordering and then sort the returned entities with code.)

Comment: As far as I understand, the ancestor: yes would have to be configured in the parent and is not required here, or?

Comment: Your names make it pretty tricky to understand what's going on ... You need the index, with ancestor: yes, on whatever kind you're querying for. Whatever config.DatastoreQuestionInDuelKind is.

Comment: Normally the log or excption will show the exact Index definition required. (at least in python and java)